# WebServer is inaccessible

Tags: linux, centos, php, web-server, httpd

I have done an install of httpd and php on my new centos server.

```
yum install httpd php -y
```

I have done hundreds of webserver installs but for some strange reason I seem to be having troubles.

When I go to the servers IP I get

```
This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Although when I do a wget localhost it downloads the index.html file in the web directory without problem.

This means the web server is indeed working, just not accepting requests from my outside connection.

I have researched, there is no articles on this problem.

I have never had such a strange problem in my life.

Edit:

I have tried updating firewall

```
[root@zh-px3 ~]# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
[root@zh-px3 ~]# /etc/init.d/iptables save
-bash: /etc/init.d/iptables: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Check your firewall rules.

Comment: Hey EEAA, thanks for the comment I have tired the following 


[root@zh-px3 ~]# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
[root@zh-px3 ~]# /etc/init.d/iptables save
-bash: /etc/init.d/iptables: No such file or directory

Comment: Please don't paste code into comments. Instead, edit your question and place them in proper code blocks.

Comment: I have just done so

Comment: None of those commands would have any effect on your firewall.

Comment: Are you using AWS and Amazon Linux? if so it does not have `iptables` pre-installed as we will use Security Groups to allow incoming port instead.

Comment: Sorry Chris Lam and Michael Hampton, I was away. I am back now. I am currently not using AWS or Amazon Linux

Comment: I have found a firewall option on my host and made the following changes but still no cigar http://prntscr.com/71oo91

Comment: Also check that the httpd server listens on your public IP also, not just the loopback interface. If you run `netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "`  you'll get a list of listening processes. Check that the list includes either "0.0.0.0:80" or "[your-public-ip]:80 instead of or in addition to "127.0.0.1:80" and ":::80".